# Making CSS cards slightly transparent

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

I want to make something like this: [image]

As you can see, the adjacent borders in the center are slightly darker than other parts. How to make it with CSS?

Comment: Use a gradient with alpha for the background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated # 2023-08-22

It seemed like a good idea to illustrate the animation as well. My original response can be read below.

It's quite simple. We set up a listener for mouse movement events using JavaScript. When this happens, we adjust the position of the `.blob` class based on the position of the `.fakeblob` (fixed position) class and the current cursor position. This way, as you move the mouse cursor, a faint circle follows along on the cards. By using CSS z-index settings, we ensure that the circle is only visible within the cards. Have fun experimenting with the pattern!

The idea was inspired by the [code of "yxsh"](https://codepen.io/yxshv/pen/JjaRZmb).

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div");

/* event listener for mouse moving */
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (ev) => {
  /* set blob on all elements */
  all.forEach((e) => {
    const blob = e.querySelector(".blob");
    const fakeblob = e.querySelector(".fakeblob");
    const rec = fakeblob.getBoundingClientRect();
    blob.style.opacity = "1";
  
    blob.animate([{
      transform: `translate(
        ${(ev.clientX - rec.left) - (rec.width / 2)}px,
        ${(ev.clientY - rec.top) - (rec.height / 2)}px
      )`
    }], {
      duration: 300,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  /* to animation */
  --blob-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  --blob-size: 123px;
  --blob-strong: 30px; /* circle: 30+ px, square: 0 */
  --blob-radius: 20%; /* circle: 50%, square: 0 */
}

/* grid */
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYZq3.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

/* element */
.grid > div {
  position: relative; /* <--- to animation */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
}

/* element parts: inner, blob, fakeblob */

/* inner: to readable content */
.grid > div > .inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px); /* <--- to readable text */
}

/* blob: to animation */
.grid > div > .blob {
  filter: blur(var(--blob-strong));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--blob-size);
  height: var(--blob-size);
  border-radius: var(--blob-radius);
  background: var(--blob-color);
}

/* fakeblob: to animation */
.grid > div > .fakeblob {
  display: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--blob-size) * 0.8);
  height: calc(var(--blob-size) * 0.8);
  border-radius: var(--blob-radius);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="fakeblob"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="fakeblob"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="fakeblob"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="fakeblob"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Original Answer

Can use [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) or [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient).

To set a gradient background, you can use the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) parameter. For a gradient border, you can use [`border-image-source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-source).

Your request wasn't very clear, but I assume you want to direct the endpoints of the four elements towards the center of the grid. In that case, I had to individually set the gradient for both the background and the border at each of the four elements to radiate in the desired direction.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYZq3.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); /* if linear-gradient() not working on browser */
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid div:nth-child(1) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 100%);
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
}
.grid div:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 100%);
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
}
.grid div:nth-child(3) {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 100%);
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
}
.grid div:nth-child(4) {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 100%);
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: The logic is exactly what I wanted! Massive thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to play with the settings a bit to get exactly what you want, but here's an example using image mask. I used mask because it can also cover a border on the component. I couldn't get it to account for a box shadow however, and the transparency would also effect any content in the card. To avoid that you'd need to layer two elements.

An alternative is to use the transparent gradient for the card background and forget about mask altogether, but then it wouldn't fade the border.  I only saw a border on the first box and not the others, so not entirely sure what you wanted. Exactly as the image shows? You'd probably need to adjust each of the 4 boxes individually and likely need to wrap multiple elements together to get the exact appearance.

```css
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #4BC0C8, #C779D0, #FEAC5E); 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4BC0C8, #C779D0, #FEAC5E); 
}

.card{
  
  width:200px;height:200px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(53,56,57,1) 0%, rgba(53,56,57,1) 100%);
  border:2px solid #888;
  
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));


-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);

    
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

</div>
```